# I get an error when running ` rails g` on top of ruby 1.8.7 (2011-12-28 patchlevel 357) [i386-mingw32]

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have both ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.2 installed on my system. I have a rails project that I initially built with ruby 1.9.2; but because I heare 1.8.7 is faster, I am trying to switch and finish it using ruby 1.8.7. However, whenever I run certain commands, right now its Rails g, I get the following output in my terminal:

```
    C:\Users\Edu\workspace\tasks>rails g
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/depende
ncies.rb:234:in `load': C:/Users/Edu/workspace/tasks/config/initializers/session
_store.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end (SyntaxError)
...sion_store :cookie_store, key: '_tasks_session'
                              ^
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_su
pport/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_su
pport/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_su
pport/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_su
pport/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_su
pport/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.r
b:556
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.r
b:555:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.r
b:555
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initiali
zable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initiali
zable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initiali
zable.rb:55:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initiali
zable.rb:54:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initiali
zable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/applicat
ion.rb:96:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/railtie/
configurable.rb:30:in `send'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/railtie/
configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from C:/Users/Edu/workspace/tasks/config/environment.rb:5
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/applicat
ion.rb:83:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/applicat
ion.rb:83:in `require_environment!'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands
.rb:22
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6
```

From reading other problems, it has to do with  1.8 not understanding some of the syntax of rails 3.1. My question is, are there any resources for getting this resolved? I really like to added speed of 1.8.7 in my development and testing of apps.  if not, are there any other suggestions to speed up my development?

Comment: What do you mean by "added speed of 1.8.7"? 1.9.x is faster than 1.8.x in [every](http://rubychan.de/share/yarv_speedups.html) [benchmark](http://programmingzen.com/2010/07/19/the-great-ruby-shootout-july-2010/) I could [find](http://nebulab.it/en/nebulog/ruby-performance-showdown). Or have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You (or someone else) has generated the application using Ruby 1.9. This means that it is using the new-to-1.9 variant of hashes (`key: value`) rather than the 1.8 version (`:key => value`).

You will need to update this to be the latter inside `config/initializers/session_store.rb` if you want to use this application on 1.8.7.

Comment: I find that if I fix this hash, I run into the same problem with a number of other files that use the same 1.9 hash variant. is there a way to go through and change this through out my application?

Comment: Other than by running your server and fixing this up as they crop up, nope.

Comment: I think I'm finally starting to understand the RoR stack a little better.